# Anaconda Navigator not starting in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Anaconda suddenly stopped working today. So, I uninstalled and re-installed it again. But it is still not working.

I ran `anaconda-navigator` from the command prompt and I got the following error.

```
(base) C:\Users\biles>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 37, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.analytics import GATracker
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 44, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.external.UniversalAnalytics import Tracker
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\external\UniversalAnalytics\Tracker.py", line 28, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import (HTTPSHandler, Request, build_opener,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'six.moves.urllib.request' (unknown location)
```

I installed `OpenSSL 1.1.1d` from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

But still not working.

---

Tried updating anaconda but got the following error.

```
(base) C:\Users\biles>conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

---

`jupyter-notebook` is also not working.

```
(base) C:\Users\biles>jupyter-notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\biles\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run it by manually clicking on the shortcuts b Jupiter notebook in start menu. I believe that anaconda is only for use to access other applications. Try to run those applications separately through their search and see if it works. If it does not, it will spit out an error that you can understand a debug. This process usually works for me. Please comment for specification.

Comment: Starting the applications from their respective shortcuts was not working that is why I ran them from the command prompt (to get some error)...